# Tilt needs to be between 0 and 90 inclusive

Tags: android, google-maps

I've got very strange crash report from a user:

> Exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: **Tilt needs to be between
> 0 and 90 inclusive: NaN**   at m.nq.c
> (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@233614037@23.36.14
> (150400-0):10)   at
> com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition.
> (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@233614037@23.36.14
> (150400-0):35)   at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.d.a
> (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@233614037@23.36.14
> (150400-0):3)   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.api.d.b
> (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@233614037@23.36.14
> (150400-0):15)   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.api.a.run
> (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@233614037@23.36.14
> (150400-0):13)   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback
> (Handler.java:938)   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage
> (Handler.java:99)   at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:233)   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8010)   at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke   at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
> (RuntimeInit.java:631)   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main
> (ZygoteInit.java:978)

But I never use any tilt in map or it's camera operation. What else may produce it, does somebody know?

com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0

Comment: even though you are not using tilt, try to send a tilt number see if the error exists

Comment: thanks, but no errors. I suspect, this is something in map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom or newLatLngBounds... but why tilt?..

Comment: Please file a bug in the Public Issue Tracker: https://developers.google.com/maps/support#issue_tracker